# WebSphere Portal 8 Admin Console not loading

Tags: websphere-portal

I just installed Portal 8 on a Windows 7 Virtual Machine and when I try to access the admin console by going to `https://localhost:10037/ibm/console` it just stays like it is loading, but never does.  I can access the portal fine by going to `http://localhost:10039/wps/portal`.  Has anybody encountered this?

Comment: Admin console port is 10032, try https://localhost:10032/ibm/console

Comment: Thanks that was it.  Interesting that the first time I did a netstat port 10032 did not show up as listening only 10039 and 10037.